# nodejs request callback is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm using cardi module from npm and when I use the fromUrl method of this module, my callback is not called. I digged into source code of the module and see that the part causing this situation is the **request** method. I copied the part to a new file, added logs and run it and it really doesn't print any results or errors/exceptions.

It is most probably caused by the url I gave: **http://www.basedesign.com** since it is working with any other urls. It only logs **start** string in the beginning. After that it does not logs **Response received** or **Exception Occured**. If I use any other url, it successfully prints **Response received**. How this basedesign url may be causing this issue?

Edit: My nodejs version is v0.10.44 and request version is 2.72.0.
This issue doesn't occur on newer versions of nodejs however I need to use v0.10.x version of node.

```
var request = require('request');
console.log('start');
try {
    var url = 'http://www.basedesign.com';
    var useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36';
    var jar = request.jar();
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        followAllRedirects: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': useragent
        },
        jar: jar
    };

    request(options, function (error, resp, body) {
        console.log('Response received');
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
} catch (exception) {
    console.log('Exception occured');
    console.log(exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I tried by pasting your exact code in the [Try it page](https://tonicdev.com/npm/request) for [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and I get **`Response received`** as the result.

---

**EDIT**

Testing at [tonicdev.com](https://tonicdev.com/), I found that it doesn't work until Node.js vs 4.4.x. Check out [API changes between v0.10 and v4](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.10-and-v4#http) to see what changed with `http` in Node. I cannot identify the exact cause, but my guess is that it is with Node's handling of the request/response and not `request` or your code.

Comment: Can you please try on node version 0.10.44?

Comment: @erdem If possible, update your versions of `node` and `request` to the latest stable versions. Please add your `node` and `request` versions to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse. I updated the question. However, I cannot update my version of node. My code is part of big project and it is using node v0.10.x.

Comment: actually since it is working with 4.4 and not working with 4.3, it should be something related with the update from 4.3 to 4.4. However, I checked the changelog and couldn't find something that could solve the problem yet.